# Javascript: Loading data from Firebase DB into generated input fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure:

[image]

Using `Total` (which is count of `R` aka routes) I generate 3 input boxes using the code here:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Lane').child('Total')

function calcVelocity(snapshot) {
   var td;

   td = snapshot.val();

   return td;
}

function getVelocity() {
   return rootRef.once('value').then(calcVelocity);
}

getVelocity().then(function(vel) {
    for(i =0; i < vel; i ++){
        document.getElementById("insert_lanes").innerHTML +=  '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="R'+i+'" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="Freq Rank"><br>'
    }
```

It works fine, there are 3 input boxes generated with ids `R1` `R2` `R3`.

---

Now to load data:

```
function f1(snapshot){
    var hol;
    hol = snapshot.val();
    return hol
}

function f2(i){
    return firebase.database().ref('Lane/R'+i+"/Dest").once('value').then(f1)
}

for(y =0; y<3; y++){
f2(y).then(function(veg){
    document.getElementById("R"+y).value = veg;
})
}
```

**This throws an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`**

However when I do it for only one of them it works:

```
function f1(snapshot){
    var hol;
    hol = snapshot.val();
    return hol
}

function f2(i){
    return firebase.database().ref('Lane/R'+i+"/Dest").once('value').then(f1)
}

y=1
f2(y).then(function(veg){
    document.getElementById("R"+y).value = veg;
})
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break my response in 2 parts: Problem and Solution.

#### Problem 1

The problem is with the asynchronous calls of the `firebase` function. Let's do some digging, which will make things clear. I've added some `console` outputs to see where this goes. Note that I've also declared `y` outside these functions to keep track of the loop iterations.

```
var y = 0;

function f1(snapshot) {
    console.log("in f1", y);
    var hol;
    hol = snapshot.val();
    console.log("in f1 hol", hol, y);
    return hol;
}

function f2(i) {
    console.log("in f2", y);
    return firebase.database().ref('Lane/R' + i + "/Dest").once('value').then(f1);
}

for (; y < 3; y++) {
    console.log("in for", y);
    f2(y).then(function(veg) {
        console.log("resolved", y);
        document.getElementById("R" + y).value = veg;
        console.log(y);
    })
}
```

When you run this the output will be something like this:[image]

The `f1` function will run only when the asynchronous call by `firebase` is resolved (`then` does this). So this request, let's say, goes in some queue, but that does not stop the other functions from executing as the work is already done and the request has been placed by `f2`. If you see the image and relate it to the code, you will see that we start getting the response from `firebase` by the time value of `y` has incremented and reached `3`. The `document.getElement` then executes but there is only the final value of `y` to be considered, all other values are past now. In other scenario it may happen this might get/not get resolved by the time for loop ends. This causes inconsistencies.

For one value, it's straight forward, because there is only one value to be resolved and one corresponding field to be filled. So there are no inconsistencies. In short, it is unpredictable.

#### Problem 2

Let's review another concurrency problem. Apparently, when you access the input fields to fill them, they are not even there! They are yet to be added in the DOM. This is again a complicated case of resolving the callbacks or promises.
That's probably why `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null` is coming up.

#### Solution

Have a look at the following piece of code. I have tried to change as less as possible and make it work.

**getVelocity**

```
getVelocity().then(function(vel) {
    //pass the value of Total in vel

    for (var i = 0; i < vel; i++) { //vel = 5
        document.getElementById("insert_lanes").innerHTML += '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="R' + i + '"><br>';
    }
    // the input fields are created R0, R1, ...... 
    loadSnapshot(); //calling the next function
});
```

**After that**

```
var laneRef = firebase.database().ref('/Lane');

var getSnap = function(){
    return laneRef.once('value');
}

function loadSnapshot(){
    getSnap().then(fillInputFields);
}

function fillInputFields(snapshot){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        var v = snapshot.child('R'+i).child('Dest').val();
        // console.log(v);
        // console.log((document).getElementById('R'+i));
        document.getElementById('R'+i).value = v;
    }
}
```

I hope this will work! Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the issue is with your for loop. The issue is probably a scoping issue with the y variable on the for loop when the promises return. Try unrolling the for loop and seeing if this works:

```
f2(0).then(function(veg){
    document.getElementById("R"+ 0).value = veg;
}));

f2(1).then(function(veg){
    document.getElementById("R"+ 1).value = veg;
}));

f2(2).then(function(veg){
    document.getElementById("R" + 2).value = veg;
}));
```